# Codeigniter won't display errors on database write operations

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have debugged a few errors that were the result of something like misspelling a database field name or something like that. CodeIgniter seems to load a blank page if there is an error in your query and you're trying to do a database write operation. How can I get it to tell me that there is something wrong with the query instead of displaying a blank page? It would help a lot when debugging these kind of problems cause it takes a while sometimes to figure out that the query is messed up.

I added this to the error reporting portion of index.php to see if it may help but it still gives me a blank page:

```
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
    switch (ENVIRONMENT)
    {
        case 'development':
            error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        break;

        case 'testing':
        case 'production':
            error_reporting(0);
        break;

        default:
            exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple ideas for you, first check if `db_debug` set to true in your database config file:

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
```

You can also use the [profiler](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html) to display loads of debugging info:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

Lastly you can check the result of a suspicious query manually:

```
$this->db->_error_message();
```